# Форма thymeleaf возвращает null вместо даты

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Пытаюсь в форме выбрать дату, но контроллер кидает исключение.

Model

```
public class Session {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String text;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDateTime created;
```

Controller

```
    @GetMapping("/formAddSessions")
    public String addSessions(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        model.addAttribute("sessions",
                new Session(0, "Заполните поле", "Заполните поле", null));
        sessions(model, session);
        return "addSessions";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createSession", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createSessions(@ModelAttribute Session sessions) {
        Optional<Session> sess = this.ses.create(sessions);
        if (sess.isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:/formAddSessions";
        }
        return PATH;
    }
```

Form

```
         <form th:action="@{/createSession}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" th:object="${sessions}">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0"/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Имя</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="text">Описание</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" id="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="created">Установить время начала трансляции</label>
                    <input type="date" id="created" th:field="*{{create}}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Сохранить</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Ошибка

> Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'session' on field 'create': rejected value [2022-09-11]; codes [typeMismatch.session.create,typeMismatch.create,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDateTime,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [session.create,create]; arguments []; default message [create]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'create'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2022-09-11'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-09-11]]]

Comment: Вот этот exception `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2022-09-11` говорит, что фэйлится конвертация. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274353/how-to-use-localdatetime-requestparam-in-spring-i-get-failed-to-convert-string) есть аналогичное решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set broadcast start time

Заменил type="date" на  type="datetime-local" и всё заработало.